# How to set Isolation level in SpringData Mongo Update

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

How can i configure isolation level on `spring data-mongo`. I could not find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data MongoDB currently doesn't support that. Note that there's no general concept of an isolation level in MongoDB either. However the `update` command supports an `$isolation` keyword.

I've filed [DATAMONGO-1447](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-1447) for you.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i use this $isloation keyword in spring data mongodb ?

Comment: Ohh sorry i missed your sentence "Spring data mongodb does not support it".